# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

i am using gradle project for log4j2... and i am getting following error while creating csvlayout: 
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat***

**CsvParameterLayoutExample class**

```
package log4j_tutorial;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class CsvParameterLayoutExample {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int val1 = 10, val2 = 11, val3 = 12;
    logger.trace("Trace Message!", val1, val2, val3);
    logger.debug("Debug Message!", val1, val2, val3);
    logger.info("Info Message!", val1, val2, val3);
    logger.warn("Warn Message!", val1, val2, val3);
    logger.error("Error Message!", val1, val2, val3);
    logger.fatal("Fatal Message!", val1, val2, val3);
}
```

}

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" packages="log4j_tutorial">
<Appenders>
<File name="my_file_appender"  fileName="C:/Users/bishal.gupta/Desktop/Testing/CsvLog4jTest/application.log">
<CsvParameterLayout delimiter=","/>
</File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
   <Root level="info">
       <AppenderRef ref="my_file_appender" />
   </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**build.gradle**
for dependencies

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.createBuilder(PluginBuilder.java:149)
at   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:119)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:888)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:828)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:820)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:820)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:449)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:197)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:209)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:492)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:562)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:578)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:145)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:182)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:455)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:441)
at log4j_tutorial.CsvParameterLayoutExample.<clinit>(CsvParameterLayoutExample.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 22 more
```

i got stuck from morning ... :(

Answer (score 2):

you have to add commons-csv as a dependency.

If you use gradle as your question is tagged, add these line:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.4'
```

Comment: thnx for quick reply... i tried this in gradle but dont know why gradle was not downloading this jar... :( so i added externally... can you tell me y gradle is not downloading

Comment: @BishalGupta If the jar is not downloaded, you should get a message when you run gradle

Comment: no i am not getting any message... After building gradle when i see my build path ... there is no such commons-csv.jar file

Comment: @can you shou your build file?

Comment: dependencies {
 compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.5'compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.5'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:'+deps.springVersion
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.4'
}

Comment: dependencies { 
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.5'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.5' 
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.4' 
}

Comment: @BishalGupta i have no idea why it is not working in your case

Comment: i made new project and its downloading there... thnx a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

build.gradle was not able to download the jar i mentioned:

build.gradle : "compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.1"

So i download the commons-csv jar from below link and added externally into the project

[commons-csv.jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi)

binaries: commons-csv-1.4-bin.zip